# how to display span in column above a marked word without overlapping one another

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to tag classes to a word in a description.

In case if there are multiple tags need to be assigned to a word then I need to display those classes on top of the word one above other in a stack.

but as in the below example, the classes are getting overlapped on previous one. i.e **class2** is overlapping **class1** making it not visible. similarly **class4** hides **class3**

I tried with css properties like **flex, flex-direction, position,flex-basis** but whatever the value I gave the UI was still getting messed up. this below code is the neat UI I got as for now for debugging purpose.

```html
<div dir="auto" style="line-height: 2.5;">
  <span data-start_offset="0" data-end="41" style="white-space: break-spaces;">Metaphysics continues asking "why" where </span>
  <span>
    <span style="position: relative;">
      <mark id="06aabd50-2b2a-4b45-bb5a-311630c7b2e8" data-start_offset="41" data-end="48" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(173, 164, 189); opacity: 1; position: relative; padding: 0px 4px; cursor: pointer;">science <span style="font-size: 0.7em; line-height: 1.5; background-color: rgb(173, 164, 189); opacity: 1; left: 0px; position: absolute; padding: 0px 5px; font-style: italic; pointer-events: none; top: -11px; font-weight: bold; margin-left: 0px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">class1</span>
        <span style="font-size: 0.7em; line-height: 1.5; background-color: rgb(173, 164, 189); opacity: 1; left: 0px; position: absolute; padding: 0px 5px; font-style: italic; pointer-events: none; top: -11px; font-weight: bold; margin-left: 0px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">class2</span>
      </mark>
    </span>
  </span>
  <span data-start_offset="48" data-end="194" style="white-space: break-spaces;"> of fundamental physics is based of fundamental physics is based of fundamental physics is based</span>
  <span>
    <span style="position: relative;">
      <mark id="977c207e-92ca-4176-af01-0b6b01afe578" data-start_offset="78" data-end="84" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(231, 131, 210); opacity: 1; position: relative; padding: 0px 4px; cursor: pointer;">theory <span style="font-size: 0.7em; line-height: 1.5; background-color: rgb(231, 131, 210); opacity: 1; left: 0px; position: absolute; padding: 0px 5px; font-style: italic; pointer-events: none; top: -11px; font-weight: bold; margin-left: 0px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">class3</span>
        <span style="font-size: 0.7em; line-height: 1.5; background-color: rgb(231, 131, 210); opacity: 1; left: 0px; position: absolute; padding: 0px 5px; font-style: italic; pointer-events: none; top: -11px; font-weight: bold; margin-left: 0px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">class4</span>
      </mark>
    </span>
  </span>
  <span data-start_offset="84" data-end="194" style="white-space: break-spaces;"> of fundamental physics is based on some set. of fundamental physics is based on some set. of fundamental physics is based on some set. of fundamental physics is based on some set. of fundamental physics is based on some set. of fundamental physics is based on some set.of fundamental physics is based on some set. of fundamental physics is based on some set.of fundamental physics is based on some set.of fundamental physics is based on some set. of fundamental physics is based on some set. of fundamental physics is based on some set. of fundamental physics is based on some set. of fundamental physics is based on some set. of fundamental physics is based on some set.of fundamental physics is based on some set. of fundamental physics is based on some set.of fundamental physics is based on some set.</span>
</div>
```

**Expected output**

the classes should be shown in a column one above the other on top of word. Then the line height should grow/adjust accordingly. can anyone help me

*class1*
*class2*
**Tagged Word**

Answer (score 1):

> compare your snippet if it does not will working fine then let me know into a comment below

```css
mark{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column-reverse;
}
.child{
  display:inline-block;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

div .child:not(.last-child) {
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
/* make sure you add the last child to this class .last-child, because of we don't need to add extra margin to the last child element 
*/
```

```html
<div dir="auto" style="line-height: 2.5;">
  <span data-start_offset="0" data-end="41" style="white-space: break-spaces;">Metaphysics continues asking "why" where </span>
  <span class="child">
    <span style="position: relative;">
      <mark id="06aabd50-2b2a-4b45-bb5a-311630c7b2e8" data-start_offset="41" data-end="48" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(173, 164, 189); opacity: 1; position: relative; padding: 0px 4px; cursor: pointer;">science <span style="font-size: 0.7em; line-height: 1.5; background-color: rgb(173, 164, 189); opacity: 1; left: 0px;  padding: 0px 5px; font-style: italic; pointer-events: none; top: -11px; font-weight: bold; margin-left: 0px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">class1</span>
        <span style="font-size: 0.7em; line-height: 1.5; background-color: rgb(173, 164, 189); opacity: 1; left: 0px;  padding: 0px 5px; font-style: italic; pointer-events: none; top: -11px; font-weight: bold; margin-left: 0px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">class2</span>
      </mark>
    </span>
  </span>
  <span data-start_offset="48" data-end="194" style="white-space: break-spaces;"> of fundamental physics is based of fundamental physics is based of fundamental physics is based</span>
  <span class="child last-child">
    <span style="position: relative;">
      <mark id="977c207e-92ca-4176-af01-0b6b01afe578" data-start_offset="78" data-end="84" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background: rgb(231, 131, 210); opacity: 1; position: relative; padding: 0px 4px; cursor: pointer;">theory <span style="font-size: 0.7em; line-height: 1.5; background-color: rgb(231, 131, 210); opacity: 1; left: 0px;  padding: 0px 5px; font-style: italic; pointer-events: none; top: -11px; font-weight: bold; margin-left: 0px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">class3</span>
        <span style="font-size: 0.7em; line-height: 1.5; background-color: rgb(231, 131, 210); opacity: 1; left: 0px;  padding: 0px 5px; font-style: italic; pointer-events: none; top: -11px; font-weight: bold; margin-left: 0px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">class4</span>
      </mark>
    </span>
  </span>
  <span data-start_offset="84" data-end="194" style="white-space: break-spaces;"> of fundamental physics is based on some set. of fundamental physics is based on some set. of fundamental physics is based on some set. of fundamental physics is based on some set. of fundamental physics is based on some set. of fundamental physics is based on some set.of fundamental physics is based on some set. of fundamental physics is based on some set.of fundamental physics is based on some set.of fundamental physics is based on some set. of fundamental physics is based on some set. of fundamental physics is based on some set. of fundamental physics is based on some set. of fundamental physics is based on some set. of fundamental physics is based on some set.of fundamental physics is based on some set. of fundamental physics is based on some set.of fundamental physics is based on some set.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: hey did u removed some css, can u add some description.

Comment: sorry I forget to add, I remove Position property from the span tag.

Comment: hi for long texts this is not working, can u please replace the last span element as I updated in the question and check. so that the overall text will appear in new line. I appreciated your efforts and timely answer but  unfortunately this is not working. kindly try it once by adding long text.

Comment: One hint, u can use `flex-flow: row wrap;` but the line are not properly filled in a row leaving lot of space at the end. is it possible to fix it, Kindly have a look at it and update your answer.